# override skipNullOn="everywhere"

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have divided my dataweave script into modules, and I have used `skipNullOn="everywhere"` in the main dwl, so all the null values in all the modules are skipped. But, I don't want to skip the null values of a particular modules. How do I override(nullify) the skipNullOn="everywhere" for that particular module.

Input:

```
<XML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ABC xsi:nil="true"/>
    <DEF/>
</XML>
```

dataweave code:

```
%dw2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
payload.XML
```

Expected Output(
json):

```
{
"ABC": ""
}
```

Getting Output(json):

```
{

}
```

Comment: Please provide some examples of how you use the module and the main script.

Comment: @[aled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721855/aled) Please Find the Input and Expected Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am answering it pretty late, I am not sure if this of much help to you. Anyways, you can have the list of nodes for which you want to skip the 'skipNullOn' check in a comma separated format in the property file. And then you try something similar as I have here below, which will help you iterate over all the nodes and then achieve the output as you desire:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
var toSkipNullOn='ABC,XYZ'

fun checkNull(key,val) = if((toSkipNullOn splitBy(',')) contains(key as String)) ''  else null
---
payload.XML mapObject (v0, k0, i0) -> 
{
    (k0):checkNull(k0,v0) 
}
```

In this example I have hardcoded the node names (ABC,XYZ) to the variable toSkipNullOn. Instead  of that you'll have to read it from the property file as `p('key-name')` and assign it to toSkipNullOn.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly write the logic for that field, should be something like this

```
%dw2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
"ABC": if (payload.XML.ABC_val !=null ) else ""
}
```

Comment: <ABC xsi:nil="true"/>, this indicates that ABC element is null. but I want to place a "" for all such elements which have xsi:nil="true"

Comment: Only if DataWeave supports xsi:nil. I'm not sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround, to get the expected result. Use two dataweave

**1st Dataweave** (wherever you get "nil", syntax need to be updated as the below one)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"

ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
---
{
ABC @( xsi#nil:"true"): payload.ABC ,
DEF : payload.DEF
}
```

**2nd Dataweave**

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

You can then replace null with "" easily.